# postgres: DB-load per accessed object

Tags: postgresql

What tables, indexes etc. got I/O in the past 5 minutes or past hour etc. and how much in terms of rows-read/s, rows-written/s bytes-read/s bytes-written/s ?

Is a question I would like to be able to answer. Preferably even with knowing how much was serviced from buffer and how much from disk.

Is there a view to see this? Any way to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STATIO-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) `pg_statio_all_tables` and `pg_statio_all_indexes` views that contain this information.

Comment: This is awesome - Thanks so much